# How to Add an Index to an Index

Tags: python

OK. This is my first time asking a question so please don't be too complicated with me. I am trying to set up my Python program so that it takes a list of three different categories of scores: quizzes, programs, and tests, and puts them in a list. My code looks like this:

```
QUIZ_GRADES = int(input("How many quiz grades? "))

PROGRAM_GRADES = int(input("How many program grades? "))

TESTS = int(input("How many tests? "))

def main():

globalConstantList = [QUIZ_GRADES, PROGRAM_GRADES, TESTS]

scoreList = [0] * (QUIZ_GRADES + PROGRAM_GRADES + TESTS)

returnedScoresList = getGrades(globalConstantList,scoreList)

#totalList(totalScore[scores])

#userOutput()

print(returnedScoresList)


def getGrades(globalConstantList,scoreList):

    for eachScore in globalConstantList:

    #totalScoreList = 0.0

    index = 0

        for index in range(QUIZ_GRADES):

            print("What is the score for quiz", index + 1)

            scoreList[index] = float(input())

        for index in range(PROGRAM_GRADES):

            print("What is the score for program", index + 1)

            scoreList[index] = float(input())

        for index in range(TESTS):

            print("What is the score for test", index + 1)

            scoreList[index] = float(input())

        return scoreList


main()
```

(Sorry if everything has not been placed in the code sample- FYI the syntax is correct.)

**HERE'S MY ISSUE:** Every time I run my code, it will add all my `QUIZ_GRADES` values to the `scoreList[]` list from the `QUIZ_GRADES` for-loop, but then when I run the `PROGRAM_GRADES` for-loop, it will take out my original values (from `QUIZ_GRADES`) and put in `PROGRAM_GRADES`). For example, if I enter 99, 98, and 97 for my quiz scores, and 96 for my program score, it will erase the initial 99 and place in the 96. Is there a way I can fill in the entire `scoreList` without erasing any of my values? Thanks

Comment: scoreList.append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be appending to the list:

```
scoreList.append(float(input()))
```

in every loop, assuming `scoreList` is empty when the function starts. Thus, your code should become:

```
def main():
    globalConstantList = [QUIZ_GRADES, PROGRAM_GRADES, TESTS]
    # scoreList = [0] * (QUIZ_GRADES + PROGRAM_GRADES + TESTS)
    returnedScoresList = getGrades(globalConstantList)
    #totalList(totalScore[scores])
    #userOutput()
    print(returnedScoresList)

def getGrades(globalConstantList):
    scoreList = []
    for eachScore in globalConstantList:
        #totalScoreList = 0.0
        index = 0
        for i in range(QUIZ_GRADES):
            index += 1
            print("What is the score for quiz", index)
            scoreList.append(float(input()))
        for i in range(PROGRAM_GRADES):
            index += 1
            print("What is the score for program", index)
            scoreList.append(float(input()))
        for i in range(TESTS):
            index += 1
            print("What is the score for test", index)
            scoreList.append(float(input()))
    return scoreList

main()
```

Alternatively use `start` and `stop` parameters of `range()`:

```
def main():
    globalConstantList = [QUIZ_GRADES, PROGRAM_GRADES, TESTS]
    scoreList = [0] * (QUIZ_GRADES + PROGRAM_GRADES + TESTS)
    returnedScoresList = getGrades(globalConstantList, scoreList)
    #totalList(totalScore[scores])
    #userOutput()
    print(returnedScoresList)

def getGrades(globalConstantList, scoreList):
    for eachScore in globalConstantList:
        #totalScoreList = 0.0
        #index = 0 <-- not needed
        for index in range(QUIZ_GRADES):
            print("What is the score for quiz", index + 1)
            scoreList[index] = float(input())
        imin = QUIZ_GRADES
        for index in range(imin, PROGRAM_GRADES + imin):
            print("What is the score for program", index + 1)
            scoreList[index] = float(input())
        imin += PROGRAM_GRADES
        for index in range(imin, TESTS + imin):
            print("What is the score for test", index + 1)
            scoreList[index] = float(input())
    return scoreList

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted to write

```
for index in range(QUIZ_GRADES):
  index+=1
  print("What is the score for quiz", index)
  scoreList[index] = float(input())
```

and similar for the other for loops.  That print(..,index+1) does not increment index, and in each for loop index starts from 0. Therefore, at the beginning of each for loop scoreList[index] evaluates to scoreList[0] and it overwrites what you inserted in the previous loops.

Notice there are more elegant ways to code this. Check also the append() method